# Crystal reports change date format

Tags: vb.net, date, crystal-reports

I am working on Crystal report 2013 and I'd like to format the date in crystal report

from

> 2008-04-27

to

> April 27, 2008

what i have tried is this

```
Right click on the field -> Format Editor
Date and Time tab
Select date/time formatting you desire
```

but i can't see the date and time tab when i did this. I also use this formula below but no luck.

```
CSTR({StudentInformation.BirthDay}, "MM dd, yyyy")
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this. thanks

Comment: Looks like `BirthDay` field in database is incorrect type (not date or datetime).

Comment: It was a date format in my sql server. I double check it. [Data type](http://img7.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22275/222757074a2f3582cc300006f46e0f7b8455f7fc.png) I'm just wondering when i put my cursor into the birthday fields of crystal reports. It seems that my bday is string [Screenshot](http://img8.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22275/22275648224ec06cbd05ad6d4ff109056f5afcaf.png) I hope you can help me to solve this.

Comment: In CR, Report Options, Convert Date-Time Field - must be `To Date` or `To Date-Time`.

Comment: I follow your instructions but i can't see `Convert Date-Time Field` [Report Options screenshot](http://img7.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22275/222757571b7b79ecb639ae99e2ef67001aa05d1a.png)

Comment: This is not `Report Options` dialog, this is just `Options` dialog :)

Comment: My screenshot is an `options` dialog . Not `report options` i am sorry :) There is no `Convert Date-Time Field` in the options dialog

Comment: There is also no `Convert Date-Time Field` in the report options dialog [RepOptions](http://img8.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22275/2227579873a3f7b2b6086c95dcd6e83b1dcac484.png). I'm using CR2013

Comment: Strange, this combo is usually located below `Preview Pages...` combo. What kind of data source you are using?

Comment: OLE DB(ADO) for Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008 r2.

Comment: @Arvo it is possible to convert a string to the `date` format according to my need?

Comment: Everything is possible (and you already posted a solution), but usually correct solution is best solution. Anyway, I can't understand, where this report option is vanished and therefore can't help further :(

Comment: @Arvo Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having my research. This code solve my problem. It converts the `string` data type to `Date` and you can now easily format this according to your need.

```
DateValue({StudentInformation.BirthDay})
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is how come Birthday is being passed as a string instead of the date data type.

Answer (score 0):

create a formula for your date and in your formula set it to totext( {StudentInformation.BirthDay}, "MMMM dd, yyyy" ), then add the formula to your report instead of the field

Comment: There is an error in the formula. Here is my [Screenshot](http://img0.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22275/222756407d1e1dd841cbf92ef749f4933a52c388.png)

Comment: One thing that i also noticed is when i put my cursor into the birthday fields. It seems that my bday is string [IMAGE](http://img8.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22275/22275648224ec06cbd05ad6d4ff109056f5afcaf.png) but when I check it to the sql server and the data type of my fields is date.

Comment: Yes this error appears if the first parameter is already a string. Do you use xsd as database of your report? How do you extract the data from sql server? Are you perhaps converting it to string?

Comment: No i do not convert it to string. I double check my sql server and it was a `date` data type. Can i have other solution for this? When i put my cursor in my `date` fields. It seems that the field is a string just like in my screenshot above.